# insmod failed, debug kmod source, error is from shared/misssing.h, syscall(__NR_finit_module, fd, uargs, flags);

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls, insmod

Compile is native on armv7l linux, kernel version is same.
Compile ko file success, but insmod failed.
Download kmod source and debug, error is from file `shared/misssing.h`, code `syscall(__NR_finit_module, fd, uargs, flags);` return -1, errno = -8.
`readelf` show ko file is okay.

Comment: In case of `insmod` failing, `dmesg` output should contain useful information about that fail.

Comment: @Tsyvarev dmesg shows no extra messages after running insmod

Comment: I recompiled and tested, this time, dmesg shows 'no symbol version for module_layout'

Comment: Probably, something wrong with setup of your compiling environment. See e.g. [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14627/no-symbol-version-for-module-layout-when-trying-to-load-usbhid-ko).